# Update multiple ranges in dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have a dataframe with several columns, some of them are in a range:
mydataStart:mydataEnd. Now I want to create a new range, newdata1:newdata122 and copy the values:

I tried:

```
columns <- paste0("newdata", 1:122)

df %>%
  add_column(!!!set_names(rep(0, length(columns)), columns)) %>% 
  mutate(across(newdata1:newdata122 = mydataStart:mydataEnd ))
```

this does not work while intuitively this works:

```
columns <- paste0("newdata", 1:122)

df %>%
  add_column(!!!set_names(rep(0, length(columns)), columns)) %>% 
  mutate(across(newdata1 = mydataStart))
```

but doing it manually for each value is not an option.

Comment: Would a data.table answer using roll join be ok ?

Comment: I want to use tidyverse or vanilla R

Comment: and I prefer simple answers, that must be possible in less than 3 loc

Comment: Are you just trying to duplicate existing columns? Maybe use `cbind` - column bind?

Comment: Sorry seems I misunderstood the question then. A minimal exemple may help ensuring what you have and what you want (maybe 4 of 10 rows, or 4 from 10 columns, fromt he question I'm not sure what you're after in fact)

Answer (score 0):

We could use *cbind* with updated names:

```
d <- head(mtcars[, 1:3])
cbind(d, setNames(d[, 2:3], paste0(colnames(d)[2:3], "_new")))
#                    mpg cyl disp cyl_new disp_new
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160       6      160
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160       6      160
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108       4      108
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258       6      258
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360       8      360
# Valiant           18.1   6  225       6      225
```